# generating a sequence incrementally in python

Tags: python, generator, yield

```
    def generator_zip(seq1, seq2, *more_seqs):
    if more_seqs==():
        t=min(len(seq1),len(seq2))
        for x in range(t):
          yield (seq1[x],seq2[x])
    else:
       t=min(len(seq1),len(seq2),len(more_seqs))
       for x in range(t+1):
           z=(seq1[x],seq2[x])+tuple([more_seqs[i][x] for i in range(len(more_seqs))])
           yield z

    assert [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')] == list(generator_zip((1, 2), "abcd"))
    assert [(1, 'a', 1), (2, 'b', 2)] == list(generator_zip(range(1, 5), "abc", [1, 2]))
    list(generator_zip(range(1, 5), "abc", [1, 2],[1]))
```

but it is raising the error for the above conditon.
what is the problem here?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: the error for the condition is list index out of range @tripleee

Comment: Full traceback, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
t=min(len(seq1),len(seq2),len(more_seqs))
#                         ^
```

This isn't the minimum length of the remaining sequences. This is the number of additional sequences given. If you want the length of the shortest of a number of sequences, that's

```
min(len(seq) for seq in sequences)
```

You probably shouldn't be doing this in terms of sequences and indexing, though. `zip` works with any kind of iterable input. Get iterators over the input iterables, `next` them, and yield tuples of the results. You can let the `StopIteration` you get from the input iterators propagate to signal completion.

```
def zip2(*iterables):
    if iterables:
        iterators = [iter(iterable) for iterable in iterables]
        while True:
            yield tuple(next(iterator) for iterator in iterators)
```